# R read xlsx, NA not as characters

Tags: r

I'm trying to read an xlsx file where a whole column contains "NA", but I would like R to interpret it as NA instead of the character "NA". 
I use this line of code:

```
assignments <- read.xlsx(file="assignments.xlsx", sheetIndex=2, header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `na.strings = "NA"`.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work

Comment: At this point maybe you can just read like strings and then convert to numeric (if numeric) with `class(data$column) <- as.numeric(as.character(data$column))`

Comment: and most important do not forget that: `example <- c("ad", "antani", NA)` , and `class(example[3])` has "character" as result **BUT** `is.na(example[3])` has `TRUE` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me

```
data <- read.xlsx(file = "test.xlsx", header = TRUE)
data[data == "NA"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `read.xlsx` function, which on the basis of documentation appears to not accept the `na.strings` option that is allowed in `read.table` for example. Thus what I would do is export the xlsx file as `.csv`, and then use the `na.strings` option, as in

```
assignments <- read.table(file="assignments.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings = "NA",sep=",")
```

where the `sep` option should be whatever the separator in the exported file happens to be.

Another option of course is to just convert `"NA"` string into an `NA` value afterwards, as suggested by Adrian in his answer.

Comment: I already suggested 30 minutes ago the `na.strings` way but the OP tried and said that it did not work.